# If the dog transforms into the cat and the cat meows

Tags: present-simple

If the dog transforms into the cat and the cat meows, can I say “the dog meows (after the dog transforms into the cat)”?

If the dog transformed into the cat and meowed, we can say “the dog meowed.” The dog is not a cat now and isn’t meowing, but was a cat and meowed. “All the adults were children” makes sense even though all the adults are not children now.

Can I just say “the/my dog meows.”

Comment: I think part of what is making your question odd is that it sounds very strange here to say **a** dog (or even **a** cat), because **a** means "one of many possible ones".  We would say "**the** dog (that had become a cat) meowed" if we're talking about one specific one.

Comment: @stangdon Thank you, I fix as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you asking philosophically?

Comment: @gotube Both linguistically and philosophically.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about a nonsensical hypothetical  situation that bears little to no resemblance with reality. And as such this question will not be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a bit trouble understanding the transformation part of your question but  I don't think it affects the answer.

Regardless of whether your animal is a cat or dog, if it cannot currently *meow*, you cannot say it *meows*.  If it might currently meow depending on whether it is a cat or dog, you might say, *My dog meows when it transforms into a cat.*

If all the meowing occurred in the past, your pet *meowed*.

Comment: Then “All the adults were children” is also false because all the adults are not currently children?

Comment: @GatePending no, because "were" is past tense, unlike "meows"

Comment: @GatePending In some cases, "all the adults were children" is false (or else a metaphorical use referring to the childishness of the adults concerned).  For example, if I say "I knew that all the adults were children", that is likely to be interpreted as a backshifted form of the false (or true but metaphorical) statement "I know that all the adults are children".  Even if we were saying "All the adults were children" as a complete and non-backshifted sentence, we'd be more likely to say "All the adults were children once" or "All the adults used to be children".

Comment: Can I say just “my dog meows”?

Comment: @OmarL Can I say just “my dog meows”?

Comment: @rjpond Can I say just “my dog meows” without a when-clause?

Comment: @GatePending I guess you can, but of course this the scenario is silly enough that it's meaningless to try and figure out what's idiomatic here.